# Error while parsing json with python

Tags: python, json, parsing

The following message when parsed with python gives the error below. The message is from json file
Message:

```
"Daca nu il stiti déjà, cu siguranta o sa va smulga un zambet. O portie de motivatie pentru toata lumea. :)",
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\store_post.py", line 328, in <module>
    post_l_1 =jsonToPost.return_post_list(data2)
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\jsonToPost.py", line 20, in return_post_list
    post_message = json.dumps(read_,sort_keys = True, indent =2,skipkeys=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 195, in encode
    return encode_basestring_ascii(o)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 18: invalid continuation byte
```

The relevant code snippet is:

```
post_message = json.dumps(read_,sort_keys = True, indent =2,skipkeys=True)
post_message = json.loads(post_message)
```

Comment: `"If you do not already know, certainly I will elicit a smile. A serving of motivation for everyone. :)"`

Comment: `post_message = json.dumps(read_,ensure_ascii= False, sort_keys = True, indent =2,skipkeys=True)`

`post_message = json.loads(post_message, encoding= 'utf-16')`



We tried this and it worked for this data but gave problem for normal ascii data.

Comment: Where does `read_` come from?

Comment: its a string that contains the message and we want to convert it into ascii, and then dump it into the database

Answer (score 0):

"its a string that contains the message and we want to convert it into ascii, and then dump it into the database"

The string shown has no ASCII representation, therefore, "convert it into ascii" makes no sense. Also it sounds like you are trying to use module `json` to do the job that module `codecs` was designed for. My guess is that you are actually trying to convert the string into [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) which can encode "déjà"

You should probably also read and understand [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and then perhaps you can pose a question that makes sense.

Comment: `json.dumps` escapes all non-ASCII characters by default.

Comment: Great; so does the questioner want to escape or convert? And if escaped, what do they do with it upon retrieval? Note that they screwed around with `ensure_ascii=False` but that didn't help them understand the fundamental problem either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with Unicode carefully.  [Pragmatic Unicode, or How Do I Stop The Pain](http://bit.ly/unipain) has all the details.  You need to know what encoding that byte string is using, and then decode it properly.

Comment: The talk is good though the fact that "codepoint != user-perceived character" might deserve more light than just being one of many items in the "Fact of Life #5½". It would set correct expectations for common things like `len(unistr)` (it is not number of characters), `for c in unistr:` (it does not enumerate characters).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: i had limited time, and for the most part didn't touch on anything having to do with interpreting or understanding the Unicode.  It was a challenge just to fit in all the points to make about properly copying around text, much less making sense of it.